# Is there a verb that means "removing a plant, but removing its roots as well"?

Tags: word-request

There's the standard phrasal verb "cut down" as in "cut down a tree", that's used to refer to the act of cutting down a plant without removing a tree. I would like to know what's the verb we use to mean "removing the plant while removing its roots as well"? Is there such a verb. Let's me give you an example:

> The workers ___ several trees in order to build a big airport in the
>   area.

Comment: Is there some reason for you to think that this meaning has a one word definition in English.  What is it in you native language?

Comment: There is no such verb in English when you mean a person does it. uproot is usually for forces, like the wind. A person removes the roots of a tree. If you say removed the trees, that should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word **uproot** is in the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/uproot) as

> **uproot**
>   VERB [with object]
>
> **1** Pull (something, especially a tree or plant) out of the ground.
>
> *the elephant's trunk is powerful enough to uproot trees*

So your sentence can be

> The workers uprooted several trees in order to build a big airport in the area.

Answer (score 0):

I like the word *eradicate*:

> 1 : to do away with as completely as if by pulling up by the roots
>   // programs to eradicate illiteracy
>   2 : to pull up by the roots

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eradicate))</sub>

because it has a figurative meaning as well.

> *Eradicate*, which first turned up in English in the 16th century, comes from *eradicatus*, the past participle of the Latin verb *eradicare*. *Eradicare*, in turn, can be traced back to the Latin word *radix*, meaning "root" or "radish." Although *eradicate* began life as a word for literal uprooting, by the mid-17th century it had developed a metaphorical application to removing things the way one might yank an undesirable weed up by the roots.